# "java.io.IOException: Host is down" after crawling one hundred thousand files of mounted cifs share in Linux file system

Tags: java, linux, share, smb, cifs

I have mounted a CIFS share in Linux. I am crawling metadata of the files and reading the content as you can see in the below code sample. After crawling approximately one hundred thousand files it start throwing exception: `java.io.IOException: Host is down`

```
1.if (Files.isReadable(p)) {
2.  //checks here if the file is readable so the metadata can be populated without throwing exceptions.                        
3.  BasicFileAttributes attr = Files.readAttributes(p, BasicFileAttributes.class);
4.  metadata.setCreated(new DateTime(attr.creationTime().toString()));
5.  metadata.setOriginalSize(attr.size());
6.  metadata.setLastModified(new DateTime(attr.lastModifiedTime().toString()));
7.  metadata.setMimeType(MimeTypeUtil.getContentType(p));
8.  if(Files.getOwner(p) != null) {
9.      metadata.setOwner(Files.getOwner(p).getName());
10  }
11.}
```

It's throwing an exception when we are trying to get the mime-type at line number: 7 in above code.

```
public class MimeTypeUtil {

    private static final Tika tika = new Tika();

    public static String getContentType(Path path) {
        try {
            return tika.detect(path.toFile());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
! java.io.IOException: Host is down
! at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
! at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:272) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
! at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
! at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:254) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
! at org.apache.tika.io.ProxyInputStream.read(ProxyInputStream.java:59) ~[tika-core-1.5.jar:na]
! Causing: org.apache.tika.io.TaggedIOException: Host is down
! at org.apache.tika.io.TaggedInputStream.handleIOException(TaggedInputStream.java:133) ~[tika-core-1.5.jar:na]
! at org.apache.tika.io.ProxyInputStream.read(ProxyInputStream.java:63) ~[tika-core-1.5.jar:na]
! at org.gagravarr.tika.OggDetector.detect(OggDetector.java:52) ~[vorbis-java-tika-0.1.jar:na]
! at org.apache.tika.detect.CompositeDetector.detect(CompositeDetector.java:61) ~[tika-core-1.5.jar:na]
! at org.apache.tika.Tika.detect(Tika.java:133) ~[tika-core-1.5.jar:na]
! at org.apache.tika.Tika.detect(Tika.java:267) ~[tika-core-1.5.jar:na]
! at org.apache.tika.Tika.detect(Tika.java:248) ~[tika-core-1.5.jar:na]
! at org.abc.xyz.util.MimeTypeUtil.getContentType(MimeTypeUtil.java:19) ~[abc2-xyz-2.3.0.jar:na]
```

I am also getting the same exception when we are to obtaining input bytes from a file from mounted CIFS share in Linux file system. Please help me to identify the cause of the exception.

Comment: Is your host still running ? This kind of exception is thrown in case of connection lost or timeouts

Comment: @VinayakPingale Host machine is up. How to check if connection is lost or timeout in code? Can retry will help?

Comment: Can you know if it crashes on a specific file (by crawling on smaller sets of files) or after *a lot of work whatever it is* ?

Comment: No because we have tried 2-3 times and it ends up after different-different number of files. It had taken 4 days to crawl and then crawler stop after this exception? Is retry really help in my case?